# Text message about my tax return, fraud?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, government

I am on holiday in Russia.

I am from the United Kingdom.

I received a text message from GOV saying:

`A tax return is pending due to previous overpayments. Follow the secure link to claim your refund: http://bit.ly/2Sdl3hK`

Picture:

[image]

Is this fraud?

Answer (score 6):

## This is certainly fraud

Here are several signs:

- The message is from G0V not GOV
- The government usually don’t communicate by message but by email or post
- A message won’t link to a `bit.ly` website but a legitimate message will give a full link

## What to do:

- Block the person who sent the message
- Don’t open the link at all as it is a virus or attempting to gather details

Comment: Asking a question and then answering it yourself?  Hmmm...

Comment: Hello there! I see you are quite new. Answering questions and answering is encouraged on Stack Exchange as it imparts knowledge on other users. It’s ok though we all learn something new :)

Comment: You can add that the message is claiming a secure link yet the URL is written with an insecure protocol (HTTP)

Comment: You can suggest an edit and I’ll accept it :)

Comment: The message is quite poorly written, too - _return_ instead of _refund_, _over payments_ instead of _overpayments_.

Comment: @BobBaerker See https://money.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer; re: *"Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions."*

Comment: HMRC does send SMS messages - the ones I get are reminders to sunmit a tax assesment - and so does NHS - so government does send SMS. However in all cases do not use the reply or URL on them - go to the home page of the organiation by typing that in your browser.